# Visual Studio equivalent to Eclipse's "Show Logical Structure" watch option

Tags: visual-studio

Eclipse has a great option for the debug "Watch" window called "Show Logical Structure" which makes Collection objects **way** easier to inspect.  Instead of showing the gory member fields of an Collection instance (like a hashtable, for instance) it instead shows an easy-to-read 'Cliff Notes' version.

Does a similar option exist for Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you had a look at **VS Visualizers**

- [Cool VS 2005 Debugging Visualizers
  for ASP.NET 2.0 Development](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/12/435236.aspx)
- [A Generic List and Dictionary
  Debugger Visualizer for VS.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/ListVisualizer.aspx)
- [Write Your Own Visualizer for VS
  Debugging](http://www.devsource.com/c/a/Using-VS/Write-Your-Own-Visualizer-for-VS-Debugging/)